# How should I index a FULLNAME field in Oracle when I need to query by first and last name?

Tags: oracle, parsing, indexing

I have a rather large table (34 GB, 77M rows) which contains payment information.  The table is partitioned by payment date because users usually care about small ranges of dates so the partition pruning really helps queries to return quickly.

The problem is that I have a user who wants to find out all payments that have ever been made to certain people.

Names are stored in columns NAME1 and NAME2, which are both VARCHAR2(40 Byte) and hold free-form full name data.  For example, John Q Public could appear in either column as:

- John Q Public
- John Public
- Public, John Q
- or even embedded in the middle of the field, like "Estate of John Public"

Right now, the way the query is set up is to look for
`NAME1||NAME2 LIKE '%JOHN%PUBLIC%' OR NAME1||NAME2 LIKE '%PUBLIC%JOHN%'` and as you can imagine, the performance sucks.

Is this a job for Oracle Text?  How else could I better index the atomic bits of the columns so that the user can search by first/last name?

Database Version: Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0)

Comment: Yes, you'd want to either look into Oracle Text or look into changing/ augmenting the data model.  If you can parse out what you consider the atomic bits, those could be put in a child table that is normally indexed.

Comment: I would strongly suggest changing your data model. Title, First_name, middle_names  last_name would be much easier to deal with. You could write code to parse your existing names and convert them into this structure - I've done it before with relatively little effort - there's a limited number of titles that someone could have so you can check if it leads with one, then you can see if there's a comma etc. Once you've got this model you can just index the columns as required (I'd guess the order last_name, first_name would be the most useful).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the incoming data and it seems to be much too inconsistent to parse programmatically.

Comment: Fun fact: my wife is from South America, from a country where everyone has two last names (one from their father and one from their mother).  When we married, she took my last name, but kept her other two as well.  So, she legal has three last names.  And a middle name she goes by too.  That's the kind of stuff that makes having just a `FULL_NAME` field a bad idea if you every want to do more with it than display it.

Comment: Have a look at [Oracle Text Name Search capability](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/GUID-41C7CABC-597C-499D-BD29-326A65A0B65A.htm#CCAPP9536).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a multi-column index on both names and modify your query to use an INDEX FAST FULL SCAN operation.

Traversing a b-tree index is a great way to quickly find a small amount of data. Unfortunately the leading wildcards ruin that access path for your query. However, Oracle has multiple ways of reading data from an index. The INDEX FAST FULL SCAN operation simply reads all of the index blocks in no particular order, as if the index was a skinny table. Since the average row length of your table is 442 bytes, and the two columns use at most 80 bytes, reading all the names in the index may be much faster than scanning the entire table.

But the index alone probably isn't enough. You need to change the concatenation into multiple OR expressions.

### Sample schema:

```
--Create payment table and index on name columns.
create table payment
(
    id number,
    paydate date,
    other_data varchar2(400),
    name1 varchar2(40),
    name2 varchar2(40)
);
create index payment_idx on payment(name1, name2);

--Insert 100K sample rows.
insert into payment
select level, sysdate + level, lpad('A', 400, 'A'), level, level
from dual
connect by level <= 100000;

--Insert two rows with relevant values.
insert into payment values(0, sysdate, 'other data', 'B JOHN B PUBLIC B', 'asdf');
insert into payment values(0, sysdate, 'other data', 'asdf', 'C JOHN C PUBLIC C');
commit;

--Gather stats to help optimizer pick the right plan.
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'payment');
end;
/
```

### Original expression uses a full table scan:

```
explain plan for
select name1, name2
from payment
where NAME1||NAME2 LIKE '%JOHN%PUBLIC%' OR NAME1||NAME2 LIKE '%PUBLIC%JOHN%';

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


Plan hash value: 684176532
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |         |  9750 |  4056K|  1714   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| PAYMENT |  9750 |  4056K|  1714   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("NAME1"||"NAME2" LIKE '%JOHN%PUBLIC%' OR "NAME1"||"NAME2" 
              LIKE '%PUBLIC%JOHN%')
```

### New expression uses a faster INDEX FAST FULL SCAN operation:

```
explain plan for
select name1, name2
from payment
where
    NAME1 LIKE '%JOHN%PUBLIC%' OR
    NAME1 LIKE '%PUBLIC%JOHN%' OR
    NAME2 LIKE '%JOHN%PUBLIC%' OR
    NAME2 LIKE '%PUBLIC%JOHN%';

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1655289165
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |             | 18550 |   217K|   152   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| PAYMENT_IDX | 18550 |   217K|   152   (3)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("NAME1" LIKE '%JOHN%PUBLIC%' AND "NAME1" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "NAME1" IS NOT NULL OR "NAME1" LIKE '%PUBLIC%JOHN%' AND "NAME1" IS NOT NULL 
              AND "NAME1" IS NOT NULL OR "NAME2" LIKE '%JOHN%PUBLIC%' AND "NAME2" IS NOT 
              NULL AND "NAME2" IS NOT NULL OR "NAME2" LIKE '%PUBLIC%JOHN%' AND "NAME2" IS 
              NOT NULL AND "NAME2" IS NOT NULL)
```

This solution should definitely be faster than a full table scan. How much faster depends on the average name size and the name being searched. And depending on the query you may want to add additional columns to keep all the relevant data in the index.

Oracle Text is also a good option, but that feature feels a little "weird" in my opinion. If you're not already using text indexes you might want to stick with normal indexes to simplify administrative tasks.

Comment: I didn't even think of the fact that scanning just the index instead of the full table would be faster.  Thanks! I'm trying it out and have seen preliminary improvements of approx 20% faster on a set of 1M rows.  Will update again once I've tested against the full dataset.

Comment: Original search was over 77M rows with avg_row_len 383.  Sample search time was 187.39 seconds. 

Index is only 11M distinct keys with a max length of 80. Improved search time was 36.39 seconds.

Thank you so much for your assistance!  Based on these results I think Oracle Text may not be worth the effort to implement and will continue with the multi-column index.